# What is the command to create a letsncrypt + certbot-auto certificate for a golang server

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to create certificate for *.foobar.com

```
./certbot-auto certonly --standalone-supported-challenges http-01 -d *.foobar.com
```

But I get the error:

```
certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: --standalone-supported-challenges http-01
```

I  have google this error but I keep getting answers with example using apache servers. What is the command to make it work with a simple golang webserver serving a typical web app (html, css, js, some svgs, jpgs)

Comment: Try --manual and remove the --standalone thing

Comment: This doesn't seem to be at all Go-specific, it's just about usage for certbot. Removing go tag and recommend migrating to ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

So I followed official certbot instructions:

https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-other

and this is the command that got it working for me:

```
cd certbot # change into cerbot dir
sudo ./certbot-auto certonly --standalone -d foobar.com
```

Comment: The other thing to note here is, you can not create wildcard certificates with LetsEncrypt

Comment: @HaroonKhan, support for wildcard certificates has been introduced in ACME v2 beginning of 2018: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-and-wildcard-certificate-support-is-live/55579